# performance tuning where cpu not pinned and plenty of memory

Tags: performance, perfmon

I'm benchmarking a windows server - web application that for argument sake has a single method called parseText().

Running a single instance take less than 10ms, however when I ramp it up to 10 simultaneous requests, things slow down drastically. Say 1 second per request.

The CPU is not pinned and there's plenty of memory available. So I'm confused as to what the bottleneck is.

One thought was that the memory latency or bus bandwidth could be an issue, but I'm not sure which perfmon counters would best indicate something like this.

Can someone suggest some counters to check that may shed some light on the matter?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be either disk IO or mutexes.

For disk, Try adding physical disk, read bytes/sec and write bytes/sec and also read/sec write/sec (ie both total bytes and actual io operation counts for read and write) Make sure they aren't spiking.  Could also add queue length if you are keen. You are looking for big shifts like 10Mb/sec or lots of small IOs.

For mutexs, which might be a side effect of memory allocation (very frequent memory allocation can cause this), try adding "system" and context switches/sec and maybe system calls/sec.  These bounce a bit from general load, so get a feel first and then see what happens.

If you think it is caused by memory bandwidth (ie exhausting the FSB) then I don't think perfmon can measure that, you would need to switch to something more like vtune, which may or may not be an option for you. An example of exhausting main memory bandwidth would be a program that allocates large amounts of memory and then initialises each byte to some value, and does this LOTS. If you think this is your issue, you might need to isolate a routine using code profilers and ot her such tools, but this is hard if you are outside the program and just observing.

Comment: Thanks, yes context switches/sec and system calls/sec seem to hit a wall. I can step up the number of threads I'm load testing with and every time I exceed a specific count the context switches/sec and system calls/sec jump and perf. goes down the drain. So I guess it looks like mutexs are most likely the root cause .. what's odd is the fact that it hit this wall and then makes such a huge jump in # of context switches.